# Unable to run project after gradle build upgrade to 3.4.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I upgraded my gradle build tools to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
```

but since then I am unable to run the project and gets error

```
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot parse result path string:     
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2048)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3850)
```

It works great when i change gradle to version 3.4.1 . What could be the issue?

Edit:

My project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

 }
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
 }
}

allprojects {
 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

 }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and app build.gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "x.x.x."
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled = true

  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        resValue("string", "PORT_NUMBER", "8081")
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
  }
}

dependencies {
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
 implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.19'
 implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.1.0'
 implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
 implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
 implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
 implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
 implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0"
 implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.0.0"
 implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.0-alpha02"
 debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.6'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha02'
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02'
 annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.0-alpha02"
 annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.19'
 annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.19'
 annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.1.0'
 implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: share your module and app build.gradle files

Comment: @YashKrishanVerma added

Comment: By run the project do you mean , building or running on a device or emulator?

Comment: @YashKrishanVerma building.. works fine when i change gradle version to 3.4.1

Comment: So previously you were using 3.4.1? Or any other version?

Comment: @YashKrishanVerma yes 3.4.1